# Cannot find a submodule imported inside a module installed from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs, browserify, html-datalist

I would like to use a node.js module from https://github.com/asbjornenge/react-datalist using browserify.

I did install the module locally at my working directory.
In that directory, I created a javascript file, main.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDatalist = require('react-datalist');

var options = ['apple','orange','pear','pineapple','melon'];
React.render(<ReactDatalist list="fruit" options={options} />, document.body);
```

Then, I reactify like this:

```
browserify -t reactify main.jsx > main.js
```

So far so good, but the problem is when I want to browserify:

```
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

I got an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './components/DataList' from '...my working directory...'
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

In `...my working directory../node_modules/react-datalist/src/ReactDataList.js`, this is defined:

```
import React          from 'react'
import DataList       from './components/DataList'
import DataListOption from './components/DataListOption'
import layout         from './styles/react-datalist.styl'
```

This is unclear to me about the scope of import. I thought node.js import mechanism should work locally, but why does it try to find `'./components/DataList'` right from my working directory?

There must be some concept about importing modules I don't know yet. So I would appreciate if you can point out to some references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel embarrassed now. The problem is I didn't realize the transformation step and the bundling step are already combined into a single command line. Hence, instead of

```
browserify -t reactify main.jsx > main.js
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

Do this

```
browserify -t reactify main.jsx > bundle.js
```